# How to vectorize a function of two matrices in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Say, I have a binary (adjacency) matrix `A` of dimensions `n`x`n` and another matrix `U` of dimensions `n`x`l`. I use the following piece of code to compute a new matrix that I need.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

new_U = np.zeros_like(U)
for idx, a in np.ndenumerate(A):
    diff = U[idx[0], :] - U[idx[1], :]
    if a == 1.0:
        new_U[idx[0], :] += 2 * diff
    elif a == 0.0:
        norm_diff = LA.norm(U[idx[0], :] - U[idx[1], :])
        new_U[idx[0], :] += -2 * diff * np.exp(-norm_diff**2)

return new_U
```

This takes quite a lot of time to run even when `n` and `l` are small. Is there a better way to rewrite (vectorize) this code to reduce the runtime?

Edit 1: Sample input and output.

```
A = np.array([[0,1,0], [1,0,1], [0,1,0]], dtype='float64')
U = np.array([[2,3], [4,5], [6,7]], dtype='float64')

new_U = np.array([[-4.,-4.], [0,0],[4,4]], dtype='float64')
```

Edit 2: In mathematical notation, I am trying to compute the following:
[image]

where `u_ik = U[i, k]`,`u_jk = U[j, k]`, and `u_i = U[i, :]`. Also, `(i,j) \in E` corresponds to `a == 1.0` in the code.

Comment: Can you give example input and output data?

Comment: Are you sure that the code above is correctly doing what you want? It's iterating over every single element and then overwrites the whole row again and again. Maybe add a mathematical description of your problem to clear this up.

Comment: @w-m Apparently they are accumulating and not over-writing.

Comment: Oh, right! Still helpful to have the mathematical notation though, thanks for adding.

Comment: ...but I'm lost with the `j: (i, j)`, and where the `k`s come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `np.einsum` for the sum-reductions -

```
# Get pair-wise differences between rows for all rows in a vectorized manner
Ud = U[:,None,:]-U

# Compute norm L1 values with those differences
L = LA.norm(Ud,axis=2)

# Compute 2 * diff values for all rows and mask it with ==0 condition
# and sum along axis=1 to simulate the accumulating behaviour
p1 = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',2*Ud,A==1.0)

# Similarly, compute for ==1 condition and finally sum those two parts
p2 = np.einsum('ijk,ij,ij->ik',-2*Ud,np.exp(-L**2),A==0.0)
out = p1+p2
```

Alternatively, use `einsum` for computing squared-norm values and using those to get `p2` -

```
Lsq = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',Ud,Ud)
p2 = np.einsum('ijk,ij,ij->ik',-2*Ud,np.exp(-Lsq),A==0.0)
```

Comment: Could you please briefly annotate the code snippet? That would help to understand what is happening.

Comment: I tried to convert this code snippet from ``np.einsum`` to [pytorch.einsum](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=torch%20max#torch.einsum). The ``A==1.0`` condition throws a ``TypeError: expected torch.FloatTensor (got torch.ByteTensor)`` error. Does PyTorch use a different method?

Comment: @madman_with_a_box Not surely really. You gotta look into its docs/source code(if available).

Comment: I did dig through the docs and the source code, but I couldn't find any more information. I don't think this functionality is supported. Is there a way to compute this without using such conditional masks? i.e. just using matrices.

Comment: @madman_with_a_box That doesn't sound like an einsum issue, but more of the datatype of `A` causing the issue. So, you gotta sort that out first. Sorry, not really familiar with pytorch, so can't give any insights into the issue.